# Google Sheets conditional formatting based on relative reference using another sheet's cell values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Using Google Spreadsheets, Excel doesn't seem to have the same problem.

I have a 100-cell column; In that column, I need every cell to check relative reference using another sheet's value. The problem is that conditional formatting seems to only accept INDIRECT, which unfortunately doesn't support relative reference.

I need Cell `B3` to check `Sheet2!$G3`, and see if it is higher than 0, and if so, let the cell be green.
Therefore I want Cell `B4` to check `Sheet2!G4`; Ergo Cell `B5` to check `Sheet2!G5`, and so on.

I haven't seen the issue to be addressed yet, will appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=B1>INDIRECT("Sheet2!G"&ROW())
```

[image: 0]

Comment: for from 5th row: `=B5>INDIRECT("Sheet2!G"&ROW())`

Answer (score 0):

A basic formula-based CF rule works fine (in Excel)

[image]

EDIT - this worked for me in Sheets

```
=indirect("Sheet2!$G" & ROW()-2)>0
```

EDIT2 - on preview @player0 already has that

Comment: Just checked and excel seems to work just fine. I'm wondering if there's a way to do it on spreadsheets?