# Conditional formatting in google sheets with relative cell referencing

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google sheet where I need to dynamically update cell background color in multiple cells within a table based on the compared value of another cell in a table within the same sheet(Cell value in the reference table gets updated through a form which updates value regularly(Yes,No or NA values in ref table)

The table being referenced is in the range `B989:W1008`. And matched data in the other table; to be color coded based on string match in the reference table (Green if Yes, Red if No, empty or NA is white); is present at `C2:X21`.

The match is made on this condition: If `B989` cell value is Yes, color code for background of cell `C2` is green, No yields red, NA or Empty yields white background.

I have the conditional formula for this as `=B989="Yes"` for green  and `=B989="No"` for red but need to extend this to refer each cell individually to the next cell across the reference range. ie `C2` gets referred to `B989`, `C3` to `B990`, `D2` to `C989` and so on. I'd like to avoid manually editing in the formula for individual cells

What can I use for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `INDIRECT` to handle a cell offset, similar to what's described in [Google Sheets conditional formatting based on relative reference using another sheet's cell values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58775122/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-based-on-relative-reference-using-another-s)?

Something like this:

```
=INDIRECT("R"&ROW()+987&"C"&COLUMN()+1,FALSE)
```

This is using the optional `is_a1_notation` parameter described in https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472